# How to fix warning that function 'node_form' is not found?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am writing a drupal module.
In my module i have the following:

In my `.module` file I have:

```
function mymodule_managment_menu(){
$items = array();
$items['management/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Add Node',
    'page callback' => 'display_add',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'file' => 'file.inc',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

in my file.inc i have:

```
function uc_am_display_edit()
{
  global $user;
  $node = array('uid' => $user->uid, 'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''), 'type' => 'track', 'language' => '');
  $output = drupal_get_form('track_node_form', $node);
  return $output;
}
```

when i go to http://myhost/management/edit i get the following warnning message:

> warning: call_user_func_array()
>   expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'node_form' not
>   found or invalid function name in
>   /var/www/includes/form.inc on line
>   378.

when debugging i get to form.inc:378 which is:

```
  $form = call_user_func_array(isset($callback) ? $callback : $form_id, $args);
```

where my $callback = 'node_form'.
but still it is not defined.
of course, when i go to http://myhost/node/add/track i get the properly designed form i want.
when i debug it, i go throw thte same path of code, with the same variables value, and node_form is declared.
so my guess here is that my module is loaded before the node module, but just writing that makes doubt it, since the node module is a core module.
tried to increase my module weight value to 11 - didnt help.
please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [node_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/node_form/6) is defined in [modules/node/node.pages.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/6). That file is not loaded by default. You have to load it manually using [module_load_include](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_load_include/6) in your page callback.